# How to perform a for loop indexing the month with SQL only

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to query the sells by moth, so I tried to make 12 columns to each month. So far I wrote 12 lines, one for each month, but I would like to optimize it with a for loop indexing the number of the month `('01','02','03',...,'12')`, if possible, with only SQL (my database is an `Oracle 12c`). Here's a MWE of my code:

```
select
       a.client,
       round(sum(decode(to_char(a.data,'mm'), '01', a.sales)), 2) as jan,
       round(sum(decode(to_char(a.data,'mm'), '02', a.sales)), 2) as feb,
       round(sum(decode(to_char(a.data,'mm'), '03', a.sales)), 2) as mar,
       round(sum(decode(to_char(a.data,'mm'), '04', a.sales)), 2) as apr,
       round(sum(decode(to_char(a.data,'mm'), '05', a.sales)), 2) as may,
       round(sum(decode(to_char(a.data,'mm'), '06', a.sales)), 2) as jun,
       round(sum(decode(to_char(a.data,'mm'), '07', a.sales)), 2) as jul,
       round(sum(decode(to_char(a.data,'mm'), '08', a.sales)), 2) as aug,
       round(sum(decode(to_char(a.data,'mm'), '09', a.sales)), 2) as sep,
       round(sum(decode(to_char(a.data,'mm'), '10', a.sales)), 2) as oct,
       round(sum(decode(to_char(a.data,'mm'), '11', a.sales)), 2) as nov,
       round(sum(decode(to_char(a.data,'mm'), '12', a.sales)), 2) as dez
  from salesmov         a,
       clients          b
 where 1e1 = 1e1
   and a.codcli = b.codcli
 group by a.client
;
```

Comment: SQL does not have `FOR` loops.

Comment: You are missing two closing brackets after `a.sales` on each month's rows.

Comment: Now it's corrected, @BarbarosÖzhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL does not have `FOR` loops.

You can use a `PIVOT` statement to apply the `SUM` aggregation to all the columns being pivoted:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT client,
         EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "DATE") AS month,
         ROUND(sales, 2) As sales
  FROM   salesmov a
  WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM clients b WHERE a.codcli = b.codcli)
)
PIVOT (
  SUM(sales) FOR month IN (
    1 AS jan, 2 AS feb, 3 AS mar, 4 AS apr, 5 AS may, 6 AS jun,
    7 AS jul, 8 AS aug, 9 AS sep, 10 AS oct, 11 As nov, 12 AS dec
  )
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE salesmov (client, "DATE", sales, codcli) AS
SELECT 1, ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2022-01-01', LEVEL - 1), 100 * LEVEL, 1
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2022-01-01', LEVEL - 1), 25 * LEVEL, 1
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12;

CREATE TABLE clients (codcli) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CLIENT | JAN | FEB | MAR | APR | MAY | JUN | JUL | AUG | SEP | OCT | NOV | DEC |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 100 | 200 | 300 | 400 | 500 | 600 | 700 | 800 | 900 | 1000 | 1100 | 1200 |
> | 2 | 25 | 50 | 75 | 100 | 125 | 150 | 175 | 200 | 225 | 250 | 275 | 300 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=10ccbedaa6ae69bc9b5595608eee218a)*